# Unexpected token on }, class foo extends Component{

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Line 16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

```
  14 | },
  15 | 
> 16  class burgerBuiler extends Component{
     | ^
  17 |     state={
  18 |         ingredients: {
  19 |             salad:0,
```

Comment: Look at like 14, that `,` is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `,` in the Line 14 after the `}`.